# How to show map of business next to google search without Google plus account?

Tags: seo, google-search

As a website developer I have to add basic SEO features into the website. One of the things I have to do is have the business' map show next to its search result.

However I do not want to a google plus account for each one, and then add 10 friends 5 reviews and jump through other hoops for something so simple.

Is there an alternative way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With "map of business next to google search" I assume you mean the [Knowledge Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_Graph)?

You could use structured data on your website. If structured correctly, Google can decide to use this for the knowledge graph. To do this you can use [schema.org](http://schema.org/) to construct the data, then embed into your webpage using JSON-LD, RDFa, or microdata. This is however no guarantee. Google will probably not trust this info straight away, especially if you are lacking the Google+ page and Google Maps entry. It probably depends on your pagerank and backlinks, there is not much info on this matter. Some say Google uses a lot of info from Wikipedia for this. Others also suggest to get your website/business in [freebase](https://www.freebase.com/), since Google uses that website for data "scraping" too. Also, see [Google Structured Data](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/?hl=ca) for basic info and guidelines. I don't see anything there about Google+, so seems totally possible without it. After that see [Testing your markup](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing?hl=ca) to see if you implemented the structured data correctly and understand how Google interprets your data.

BTW. You don't need followers for your google+ page to get a knowledge graph. I made a website for a local business, created a google+ page with only me as its follower, made a local business entry in google maps, and added the structured data. The knowledge graph was visible the next day. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I will go through the resources and see if it is a good alternative. Good to know that you only need to have the G+ page and don't have to worry about reviews and followers. Guess the troubleshooting forum I saw just tried everything to resolve another user's issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to have follower on g+ for  a local business page, with that page you can see the map with pinpoint, at the side of search results